# How to simplify the finite continued fraction?

Tags: generating-functions, continued-fractions

I want to simplify the following expression for $q_i$ and $p_i$, where $i \in \{1,2,...,n \}$ and $q_i \in [0,1]$ and $p_i \in [0,1] $ , is there any standard method for it? For example, based on generating functions or ... .

The expression is

$$ \displaystyle\frac{1}{1-\displaystyle\frac{q_1 p_1}{1-\displaystyle\frac{q_2 p_2}{...}}}$$

Comment: What are $x_i$? What is a "division series"? I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @5xum The $x_i$ are variables and what OP calls "division series" is the finite continued fraction given in the question.

Comment: I made my question clearer, I hope it is clear. I just want to write above phrase simply. The number of $x_i$s  is limited to $n$

Comment: @OptimizeLife OK now I understand. I changed it a little more, because what you are calling a "series" is not really a series. It's simply an expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for your editing

Comment: Sorry to say I don't know of a way to simplify your expression though...

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The coefficient of $x_1^kx_2^\ell$ for $n=2$ is the multichoose number $\big(\!\big(\begin{smallmatrix}k\\ \ell\end{smallmatrix}\big)\!\big)$, and of $x_1^jx_2^kx_3^\ell$ is a sum of products of multichooses indexed over solutions to two linear equations. Unless you can simplify these coefficients for $n=3$, I don't think there's much hope for the general case.

Comment: You're asking for a way to simplify a general continued fraction. There's a way to compute it – after all, it's just a fraction, ordinary arithmetic will do – but no way to write a simple formula for it. Look up "simple continued fraction".

Comment: There is no point considering separate factors $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{1-\dfrac{t_1}{1-\dfrac{t_2}{1-\dfrac{t_3}{1-t_4}}}}=\frac1{1-\dfrac{t_1}{1-\dfrac{t_2(1-t_4)}{1-t_4-t_3}}}=\frac1{1-\dfrac{t_1(1-t_4-t_3)}{1-t_4-t_3-t_2(1-t_4)}}
\\=\dfrac{1-t_4-t_3-t_2(1-t_4)}{1-t_4-t_3-t_2(1-t_4)-t_1(1-t_4-t_3)}
\\=\dfrac{1-t_4-t_3-t_2+t_2t_4}{1-t_4-t_3-t_2-t_1+t_2t_4+t_1t_4+t_1t_3}.$$

With more levels, the expressions will just be polynomials of higher degree, and no simplification is possible.